# Undo refusal of app’s access to mic

Tags: security, microphone

I am using Scratch which is based on Adobe Air, I believe.

At some point I mistakenly denied access to my microphone on that program (it asked me "May Scratch access your microphone" or something along the lines through the OS, and I said "no" by mistake).

Now I can't seem to find a place where I can recover the access and allow Scratch to access my microphone.

Any ideas where that toggle would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Security & Privacy

You can control which applications have access to the computer's microphone using the Security & Privacy panel:

- System Preferences.app > Security & Privacy > **Privacy** (tab)

To modify the list, select **Click the lock to make changes.**

[image: System Preferences on macOS]